# windows phone 8 and windows 8 tablet

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8

I'm wondering how to develop an app for both Windows Phone 8 and a Windows 8 tablet? When creating a  new Windows Phone project in Visual Studio, I don't see any options to target phone and tablet devices like in Xcode. Are there any guidelines or tutorials on how to create the same app for both devices?

Comment: Check out this question for more info about code reuse:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963279/windows-8-windows-phone-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned you need to create two separate projects.

It is possible to create a library called Portable Class Library where you can put code that can be shared between a Windows Phone 8 app and a Windows Store app. See [Maximize code reuse between Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681693%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Another technique mentioned in the article is to use MVVM to be able to separate UI (which differs more between platforms) from logic (which is easier to share).

Answer (score 2):

Although they are using the same core, Windows 8 (RT) and Windows Phone 8 are distinct operating systems.  This is different that iPhone/iPad which both run iOS.

You will need to create individual projects for Windows Phone 8 and Windows RT.  If you are coding in C#/XAML, the code should be fairly portable between the two platforms.  Here is a good session from the Build conference on [how to leverage your code across Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-043).